# Make my macro so that I can "Ctrl + Right" to the next entry

Tags: macros, texstudio

I use TeXstudio and was hoping somebody could help me with this issue. I have my own shortcuts, for example I have a shortcut for fraction that gives me "`\frac{}{}`". This differs slightly from the predefined one that gives "`\frac{num}{den}`".

The nice thing about the standard shortcut is that when I press "Ctrl + Right", it moves me from the num `{}` to the den `{}` where it highlights those three letters. However with my own shortcut, "Ctrl + Right" just takes me to the very right of my whole expression.

Does anybody know how I can get this feature into my own macros?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the shortcut "Ctrl + Right" is used to move cursor to the next placeholder. In the `\frac{num}{den}` case, the `num` and `den` are placeholders (visually surrounded by rectangles). You can markup placeholders by using delimiters `%<` and `%>`. In your example, `\frac{%<%>}{%<%>}` should work.

Related documentation: [TeXstudio's user manual](http://texstudio.sourceforge.net/manual/current/usermanual_en.html), section 4.5.1